# How to move value from json property, one level up (java)

Tags: java, json, objectmapper

I have following json.

```
    {
        "Id": "357",
        "Start": 76341,
        "long": 0,
        "data": "{bytesIn:120, byteOut:120}"
    },
```

What I need to do is to take the value({bytesIn:120, byteOut:120})  from parametr "data" and move to the same level like "long", "start". The output should looks like this json"

```
    {
        "Id": "357",
        "Start": 76341,
        "long": 0,
        "bytesIn": 120, 
        "byteOut": 120
    },
```

Is there any "nice way" to do this in java, using ObjectMapper?

Comment: Probably will not be possible without some custom parsing, because the value of your data field is not JSON (there are no quotes around the props)

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you use Jackson. Add `@JsonUnwrapped` on data field

```
class YourType {
    @JsonUnwrapped
    private Data data;
}
```

Comment: I just read the docs for it. Oddly satisfying that this annotation exists.

Comment: Thanks for quickly respond! I have already tried to use  @JsonUnwrapped but in my case it dosen't work .                                                           I have something like that: class YourType {
    private String data;
}

Comment: JavaDoc says nothing about deserializing, only serializing. Does it work in reverse?

Comment: @Adam so fix your model, holding two values as string doesn't look good. I don't know any normal way of doing it, without some dirty magic.

Comment: I mean, that i have filed like private String data. And data could be for example this          "{bytesIn:120, byteOut:120}" or even this {bytesIn:120, byteOut:120, something: test} is dynamic. And my problem is, that I dont wanna display the name of property like "data": .... , I wanna seperate the value from json in this case "{bytesIn:120, byteOut:120}", and display it as property like bytesIn:120

Comment: @Adam my point is, why hold two values in string when it only generates problems?